# XMPP Room Invite Friend IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, xmpp

I am using XMPP Framework in ios. How can i invite other users for Group Chat?

```
 [xmppRoom1 inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"abc@domain.com"] withMessage:@"Come Join me"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invite multiple users one by one in MUC:

```
for (int contactIndex = 0; contactIndex <contactsToInviteArray.count; contactIndex++)
{
    NSString * inviteUserJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",[contactsToInviteArray enter code hereobjectAtIndex:contactIndex], SERVER_NAME];
    [xmppRoom1 inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:inviteUserJID] withMessage:@"Come Join me"];

}
```

Comment: Do we need to do this code before calling invite function.      
    
    _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomCoreDataStorage jid:groupJabId dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    
    [_xmppRoom activate:[ [CLXMPPDelegate sharedManager] xmppStream]];
    
    [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    
    NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
    [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"0"];
    
    [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:userMO.closrr_id history:nil];

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"Groupname"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoom inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@""] withMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Come Join me"] listusers:@" array with list of users JID "];
```